# What is the meaning of the phrase 'to the extent to which'

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context

The following is an excerpt from the newspaper 'The Hindu'.

> The Supreme Court on Friday gave the Reserve Bank of India (RBI) “a last oppotortunity” to withdraw a November 2016 Disclosure Policy to the  extent to which it stonewalls revelation of every other kind of information under the Right to Information Act, including the list of wilful defaulters and annual inspection reports.

I couldn't understand the usage of ' to the extent to which ' in this context. Can it mean 'as long as ' because the court actually wants the bank to disclose more information. Please explain.

Comment: I think the sentence is confused and not actually grammatical.

Comment: Ok. Also, Google search of ' every other' gives th meaning 'alternate' but what does it mean in this context? ('Alternate kinds' or 'all kinds ' ).

Comment: I don’t know where you copied that quote from but all the “spaces” between words were not actually spaces and it broke the word wrap.  I edited it.

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with “the extent to which” in general, it’s just not used properly here.

Comment: @Jim I don't see what is so wrong with it here. Doesn't it simply say that those parts of the policy that stonewall certain revelations should be withdrawn?

Comment: @Jim Thanks for editing. Will it be meaningful if 'as long as ' is used instead of 'to the extent to which ' ?

Comment: @We oath to creation Ok.Is the usage of 'every other' right in this context?

Comment: “To the extent to which” means “insofar as”. That is, not all information must be revealed.  The “every other kind” refers to previously defined information that the bank need not reveal. Not a very well organized article, but its meaning is clear.

Comment: @Xanne So, it means the disclosure policy should be changed such that it can stonewall the revelation of any information other than the kinds of information mentioned in RTI,names of defaulters and annual reports. Is this right?

Comment: The full article, to which you should post a link, objects to stonewalling names of defaulters etc., but allows the RBI to continue not to reveal information about interest rates etc.  The action of the Court is to require the RBI not to stonewall, but to reveal information it has thus far refused to reveal.

Comment: *Other* is a reference back to a kind of information either that the RBI has been disclosing, or that the Supreme Court thinks it is right not to disclose. We don't know which without reading the rest of the piece - but it may well be a kind of information that is covered by the Act.

Comment: I read it as meaning that they should "withdraw [the parts of the] November 2016 Disclosure Policy that result in it stonewall[ing] revelation of ..." so that the rest of the Policy can proceed to be put into place.

Comment: Maybe it means this: *The Supreme Court pressured the Reserve Bank to withdraw the portions of the 2016 Disclosure Policy which block certain types of sharing of information.*  But it also occurs to me that "to the extent to which" might mean, here, *inasmuch as*.

Answer (score 0):

Exploring the different senses and phrases of **extent** may be helpful:

**extent**  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/66951?rskey=srLI02&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> c. Phrases: to a certain, great, etc., extent, to the (full) extent
>   of. Hence: **the limit to which anything extends**; e.g. in to reach
>   the extent.

I have no comment on the grammar in said quote, and am commenting in general on the use of 'to x extent'.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "to the extent" never means "as long as". "To the extent" is actually a well known expression which is used for adding emphasis on what's being stated. It just means that the speaker reached the point beyond which he/she is unable to tolerate it.

In the following sentence "The Supreme Court on Friday gave the Reserve Bank of India (RBI) “a last oppotortunity” to withdraw a November 2016 Disclosure Policy to the extent to which it stonewalls revelation of every other kind of information under the Right to Information Act, including the list of wilful defaulters and annual inspection reports", the author is saying that the SC gave RBI a last opportunity to withdraw the said policy to the point where it (SC) denies any information under the RTI Act. Here the emphasis is on the level of withdrawal.

Comment: I don't think you have the usage of "to the extent" correct. https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/to-the-extent-of-that-to-such-an-extent-that-etc

Comment: @jimm101, could you tell me where you feel that I'm wrong in my explanation?

Comment: "It just means that the speaker reached the point beyond which he/she is unable to tolerate it." *Tolerate* isn't really what people are getting at, and doesn't match the OP's quote. In that case, they're calling for the policy to be modified so it no longer has the negative effect of "stonewall[ing] revelation of every other kind of information under the Right to Information Act".

Answer (score 0):

The Supreme Court on Friday gave the Reserve Bank of India (RBI) “a last opportunity” to withdraw a November 2016 Disclosure Policy to the extent to which it stonewalls revelation of every other kind of information under the Right to Information Act, including the list of wilful defaulters and annual inspection reports.

*To the extent to which*  means "in so far as to" Stonewalling (obstructing /withholding). So it simply goes to mean this is the last opportunity by Supreme Court to withdraw relevant portion of disclosure policy whereby RBI does not divulge the items mentioned and keeps to itself.